# Google Cloud Storage getting download link

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm working in an Asp.Net Core 2 web api for files hosted at Google Cloud Storage. The files hosted there are not public, so I can't use the `MediaLink` property of the object. I tried to make a download endpoint using `MemoryStream` but when there are many users downloading large files at once I run into memory issues.

My question is: is there a way to create something link a one-time download link for a file or something similar?

I'm also trying to implement what's described in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-object-download) but I'd need to give the bearer token to the user. I can't do that.

Any tips?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Google Cloud Storage offers a feature called "signed URLs" that is what you described: a URL that is only good for a short while to download a single file. The idea is that you craft a download URL, then use the private key of a service account to "sign" the URL. Anyone holding that final URL can use it to act as that service account for the purpose of downloading that one object.

Take a look: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/#Signed-URLs

Writing code to generate the signed URL is a bit tricky, but the client libraries provide helper methods in several languages to do it for you. You can also generate one with the gsutil command: `gsutil signurl -d 10m privatekey.p12 gs://bucket/foo`

There is a code sample for generating he signed URLs programatically  on their GitHub project: [Signed URLs](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/#signed-urls)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to Create it using C#. I'm posting here because this will be useful to someone else:

1 - [Create your private key](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program)
2 - Create and UrlSigner:

```
private readonly UrlSigner _urlSigner;
```

2 - In your class constructor:

```
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(_googleSettings.StorageAuthJson))
    {
        _urlSigner = UrlSigner.FromServiceAccountData(stream);
    }
```

`_googleSettings.StorageAuthJson` has the physical path of the json file you downloaded when creating your key.

3 - Method to get the URL:

```
public string GetSignedUrl(string bucketName, string objectName, TimeSpan duration) {
    var url = _urlSigner.Sign(bucketName, objectName, duration, null);
    return url;
}
```